# Trying to get property of non-object [laravel 5.2]

Tags: php, laravel

> project VERSION 5.2

**I am a new Laravel 5 learner. plz solve ...**

**erro**r:Trying to get property of non-object

> **Comment.php** [model]

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    //
    public function articals()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Artical');
    }

    protected $fillable = array('body','artical_id');


}
```

> **Article.php** [model]

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artical extends Model
{
    //
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    protected $fillable = array('title','body');


}
```

> **route.php** [route]

```php
 use App\Artical;
 use App\Comment;

Route::get('/', function ()
{

 $c = Artical::find(18)->comments;
  foreach($c as $comment) 
  {
    print_r($comment->body.'<br />'); 
  }
}); // working ok.....but

  $a = Comment::find(18)->articals;
  print_r($a->title); // error:Trying to get property of non-object 




}
```

> getting error:Trying to get property of non-object

***plz help me...***

[article table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYGOc.png)

[comment table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaWYL.png)

Comment: what line does it say the error is on?

Comment: And what file is it telling you that throws the error?

Comment: It means that `$a` is not an object, which means that articles is presumably null. `Article::comments()` should be `hasMany(Comment::class)` and `Comment::articles()` should presumably be `Comment::article()`. Fix the relationship will likely mean that an article is returned for the comment, meaning that `$a->title` will work

Comment: Check  `Comment::find(18)` exist or not

Comment: $a = Comment::fint(18);
print_r($a);

// output Empty Not ANY GETTING ERROR but

$a = Comment::fint(18)->articles;

// getting error:Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationships might be off. Guessing from the code the relationship is Many to many? If so, then those relationships should be belongsToMany. Also make sure you're defining the relationship and it's inverse on the right models (depending on which has the foreign key).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `articles()` relationship on your `Comment` model.

When you don't specify the foreign key on the `belongsTo` relationship, it builds the foreign key name based on the name of the relationship method. In this case, since your relationship method is `articles()`, it will look for the field `articles_id`.

You either need to rename your `articles()` relationship to `article()` (which makes sense, since there will only be one article), or you need to specify the key name in the relationship definition.

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    // change the relationship name
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    // or, specify the key name
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article', 'article_id');
    }
}
```

Note, this is different than the `hasOne`/`hasMany` side of the relationship. It builds the key name based on the name of the class, so there is no need to change how your `comments()` relationship is defined on the `Article` model.

Comment: @ShivBhargav Your other comments show that `$a = Comment::fint(18); print_r($a);` gives you empty output. That means you don't have a comment with the id of `18`. That would also be a problem.

Comment: i have 3 comments with id 18 and 2 comments with id 17 but in both id same promlem..

Comment: @ShivBhargav That doesn't make sense. Does your `comments` table not have a unique id?

Comment: plz check...
article Table::::[http://i.stack.imgur.com/PYGOc.png]

comment Table:::[http://i.stack.imgur.com/FaWYL.png]

Comment: @ShivBhargav Your `articals` table and `artical_id` field are misspelled. They should be `articles` and `article_id`.

Comment: @ShivBhargav When you do `$a = Comment::find(18)`, it is going to run the query `select * from comments where id = 18`. If that record doesn't exist, your `$a` variable will be null.

Comment: i know it is spelling problem  but in my code i use 'artical' , 'artical_id',articals(), Artical ,keyword  and in my question i change spelling but not in my original  code

Comment: @ShivBhargav To go back to your previous comment, you cannot have 3 comments with id 18. id is a unique field. Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
$a = Comment::find(18)->articles;
```

to

```
$a = Comment::find(18);
```

Comment: $a = Comment::fint(18); print_r($a);
 // output Empty Not ANY GETTING ERROR but 

$a = Comment::fint(18)->a‌​rticles;
 // getting error:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What is the output for Comment::find(18)->articles; ?